# Respect\rest nao funciona ao tentar implementar no meu projecto

Tags: php, restful, composer

Estou testando uma aplicacao web, mas preciso implentar o uso de routas e achei melhor trabalhar com Respect\rest. Segui todas as instrucoes de uso da class, mas nao consigo imprimir se quer um Ola mundo na tela, o que sera que esta errado?

Arquivo index.php

```
  use Respect\Rest\Router;
  chdir( __DIR__ . '/..');
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $router = new Router();
  $router->get('/','Hello World');
```

Fiz a instalacao da class Respect\Rest via composer, mas estou testando faz tempo nada acontece.

Aqui esta o meu composer.json

```
  {

    "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "src/App"
       }
    },
    "require": {

    "respect/rest": "^0.6.0"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja na inclusão do `autoload.php`, que por sua vez inclui todas as dependências no seu projeto.

Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use Respect\Rest\Router;

$router = new Router();
$router->any('/', function() {
    return 'Funcionou.';
});
```

PS: essa é a estrutura de diretórios com a qual trabalhei:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── index.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── composer
    └── respect
```